# Flutter locked on old pods

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I am unable to get the Flutter project to update to the latest available pods for Flutter and Firebase Plugins. I have tried deleting the pods folder and clearing flutter build cache and pod cache.

My Flutter version is:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale en-CA)
```

Output of *pod outdated*:

```
Updating spec repo `trunk`

CocoaPods 1.10.0.rc.1 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.10.0.rc.1

Analyzing dependencies
The color indicates what happens when you run `pod update`
<green>  - Will be updated to the newest version
<blue>   - Will be updated, but not to the newest version because of specified version in Podfile
<red>    - Will not be updated because of specified version in Podfile

The following pod updates are available:
- abseil 0.20200225.0 -> (unused) (latest version 1.20200225.0)
- BoringSSL-GRPC 0.0.7 -> 0.0.7 (latest version 0.0.12)
- Firebase 6.26.0 -> (unused) (latest version 6.32.2)
- FirebaseAnalytics 6.6.0 -> 6.6.0 (latest version 6.8.2)
- FirebaseAuth 6.5.3 -> 6.5.3 (latest version 6.9.1)
- FirebaseCore 6.7.2 -> 6.7.2 (latest version 6.10.2)
- FirebaseCoreDiagnostics 1.5.0 -> 1.5.0 (latest version 1.6.0)
- FirebaseFirestore 1.15.0 -> 1.15.0 (latest version 1.17.1)
- FirebaseInstallations 1.3.0 -> 1.3.0 (latest version 1.7.0)
- Flutter 1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (latest version 1.20.0)
- GoogleAppMeasurement 6.6.0 -> 6.6.0 (latest version 6.8.2)
- GoogleDataTransport 7.2.0 -> 7.2.0 (latest version 7.3.0)
- gRPC-C++ 1.28.2 -> 1.28.2 (latest version 1.32.0)
- gRPC-Core 1.28.2 -> 1.28.2 (latest version 1.32.0)
- nanopb 1.30905.0 -> 1.30905.0 (latest version 1.30906.0)
- Purchases 3.4.0 -> 3.4.0 (latest version 3.7.1)
- PurchasesHybridCommon 1.2.0 -> 1.2.0 (latest version 1.4.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a possibility that your cocopods repo is out of date.

Try the below steps

`1. Check whether the dependency versions are correct or not`

`2. flutter clean`

`3. pod repo update`

`4. delete /ios/Pods/ and /ios/Podfile.lock`